# Perl share hashmap through file

Tags: perl

Currently I have a script that collects data of the specified server. The data is stored inside a hash which I store into a file for persistence. 
If the script is being called with another server it should load the hash from the file and extend the hash with the data from the second server. Then save it back.

I use the storable module.

```
use Storable;
$recordedpkgs = retrieve($MONPKGS_DATA_FILE) if ( -e $MONPKGS_DATA_FILE);
store $recordedpkgs, $MONPKGS_DATA_FILE;
```

Obviously there is a access issue if one writes while the other has already read the file. Some data will be then lost.

What would be an ideal solution to that? Use basic file locking? Is there better ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends - what you're talking about is inter process communication, and perl has a whole documentation segment on the subject [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)
But to answer your question directly - yes, file locking is the way to go. It's exactly the tool for the job you describe.

Unfortunately, it's often OS dependent. Windows and Linux locking semantics are different. Take a look at [`flock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) - that's the basic start on Unix based systems. Take a look at: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7058

It's an *advisory* lock, where you can request a shared (read) or exclusive (write) lock. And either block (until released), or fail and return if you cannot acquire that lock.

Storable does implement some locking semantics: http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html#ADVISORY-LOCKING

But you might find you want to use a lock file if you're doing a read-modify-write cycle on the saved content.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. The problem is it should not even have shared read access. Because if one reads the file and another process write it with new information they will eventually overwrite each other.

Comment: Yes. So you'd _exclusive_ lock whilst writing - and the _read_ lock would then block (or fail) because there's an exclusive lock in force. If you're after a 'shared memory' sort of thing though, filesystem based IPC may not be the most appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I think with that I try to work it out

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a basic lock file that is checked before operations are performed upon the file, if the lock file is in place then simply make your other process either wait + check (either infinite or a set amount of times before exiting), or simply exit with an error.